# How to detect a screen's pixel's color in Python

Tags: python

I want to know how we can detect a pixel's color using pyautogui doesnt work as it gives a error `OSError: windll.user32.ReleaseDC failed : return 0` is there any alternatives to detecting a pixel's color

And my code is :

```py
import pyautogui
from time import sleep as wait
import keyboard

while keyboard.is_pressed('q') == False:
    if pyautogui.pixel(565, 171)[0] == 0:
        pyautogui.click(565, 171)
        wait(0.01)
    if pyautogui.pixel(670, 171)[0] == 0:
        pyautogui.click(670, 171)
        wait(0.01)
    if pyautogui.pixel(769, 171)[0] == 0:
        pyautogui.click(769, 171)
        wait(0.01)
    if pyautogui.pixel(873, 171)[0] == 0:
        pyautogui.click(873, 171)
        wait(0.01)
```

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include your code? see [mre]

Comment: @jtbandes i added my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by handling the error

```py
import pyautogui
from time import sleep as wait
import keyboard

while keyboard.is_pressed('q') == False:
    try:
        if pyautogui.pixel(565, 171)[0] == 0:
            pyautogui.click(565, 171)
            wait(0.01)
        if pyautogui.pixel(670, 171)[0] == 0:
            pyautogui.click(670, 171)
            wait(0.01)
        if pyautogui.pixel(769, 171)[0] == 0:
            pyautogui.click(769, 171)
            wait(0.01)
        if pyautogui.pixel(873, 171)[0] == 0:
            pyautogui.click(873, 171)
            wait(0.01)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

Comment: You should specify the type of error you are catching using `except` otherwise you might catch some other unintended errors, which is annoying when debugging